# Che cosa significa "roba da forca"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Mi conducevi spesso e volentieri fino alla serra per vedere le tartarughe. Il giorno che ne voltai una sul dorso col piede, ti mettesti a piangere. Nemmeno il giardiniere riuscì a calmarti; m’insultavi fra i singhiozzi. La tartaruga si chiamava Beatrice. 
>         Rientrasti in casa quasi correndo, il tuo protettore mi misurò uno schiaffo, la nonna prese le mie difese. **«Roba da forca»** esclamò la signora. «Stanotte avrà la febbre» disse il tuo protettore; mi guardava con occhi cattivi.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa l'espressione "roba da forca" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il termine "forca" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo contesto "roba da forca" è un’esclamazione che si dice quando è stata commessa in azione riprovevole tale da essere condannati.

La forca è il patibolo, uno strumento per impiccare i condannati a morte.

Un espressione simile potrebbe essere

> Roba da ergastolo!

Answer (score 2):

Il Sabatini Coletti definisce [forca](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/forca.shtml):

> (2) Patibolo per l'impiccagione dei condannati a morte, costituito da travi incrociate da cui pende il capestro || ***forche  caudine***, gioghi sotto i quali dovettero passare, in segno di dispregio, i Romani sconfitti dai Sanniti a Caudio nel 321.

[image]

Roba da forca, ossia roba, in questo caso comportamento,  da condannare aspramente.

Comment: Non capisco il perché del voto negativo.